# Copy/Paste Macro Pasting Randomly

Tags: vba, excel

I am having an issue copying and pasting a drop-down data validation menu from one sheet into all selected sheets. The drop-down menu seems to paste randomly instead of pasting into sheet "B22" of the selected sheets.

```
Sub TEST()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B22").Copy
'Sheets selection should be done before running macro
Selection.Range("B22").PasteSpecial xlPasteValidation
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Any suggestions on how to tackle this? I am having some difficulty finding the error in my code.

Comment: what is the reference in data validation?  Named range or just an area reference?

Comment: It is a named range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following, you need to loop through all selected Sheets instead of using Selection.Range:

```
Sub TEST()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B22").Copy
    'Sheets selection should be done before running macro
    For Each sht In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets
        sht.Range("B22").PasteSpecial xlPasteValidation
        Application.CutCopyMode = True
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Works Perfectly! It does give me a "Run-time error '1004': Application or Object not defined." But if it works it works :)

Comment: I've updated my answer, I declared sht as an Object, should have been a worksheet, I think the error should disappear now..

Comment: Yes, sorry there was a 5 minute "cool down" time before being allowed to accept an answer!

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to work with the workbook and avoid using copy/paste..

```
    Option Explicit
    Sub Test()
       Dim excel_sheet As Worksheet
       Dim sht As Worksheet
       Dim drop_down_value As Range

       Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
       Set drop_down_value = sht.Range("B22")

      'Sheets selection should be done before running macro

      For Each excel_sheet In ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).SelectedSheets
          excel_sheet.Range("B22").Value = drop_down_value.Value
      Next
    End Sub
```